# Не выводит уведомление (alert) при выполнении ajax запроса

Tags: ajax, alert

Есть некий ajax-запрос, который работает исправно, добавляет запись в БД, кладет файл куда нужно, за исключением показа уведомления (alert) при успешном или нет результате. Не показывает и все тут... Что я упускаю?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#add").click(
        function () {
            sendAjaxForm('ajax_form', 'action.php');
            return false;
        });
});
function sendAjaxForm() {
var formData = new FormData(document.forms.ajax_form);
formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: "action.php",
    data: formData,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response == 'success')
            swal({
                icon: "success",
                timer: 3000,
            });
        else {
            swal({
                icon: "error",
                timer: 3000,
            });
        }
    }
});
$('#ajax_form').ready(function () {
    window.parent.location = window.parent.location.href;
});
}
```

Comment: что за функция swal?

Comment: если это https://sweetalert2.github.io/ то оно вызывается Swal.fire(params)

Comment: Да... это sweetalert... я пробовал и тот что в комплекте с bootstrap и отдельно взятый на sweetalert.js.org... результат один и тот же - не показывает. Отдельно работает с кнопки, а вставляю к себе - тишина...

Comment: @OlegKasumoff стесняюсь спросить.. а сам плагин у вас подключен выше ваших потугов вызвать его ? Может из виду ускользнул..Что возвращает response ? Лог с консоли киньте.

Comment: @steam.apk2 Как не удивительно, но плагины подключены изначально и правильно... хотя на всякий случай перепроверил... По делу - в консоли (Chrome) никаких сообщений не выводилось, однако, опытным путем было выявлено следующее - когда отключаю обновление страницы, то что в конце кода, то все работает на ура. Теперь вопрос - как иначе можно очищать поля формы?! Иначе после того как запись легла в бд поля остаются заполненными, а это не очень очень...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем вот рабочий вариант с уведомлением и очисткой полей формы после отправки:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#add").click(
        function () {
            sendAjaxForm('ajax_form', 'action.php');
            return false;
        }
    );
});

function sendAjaxForm() {

var formData = new FormData(document.forms.ajax_form);
formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", // Метод отправки
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: "action.php",
    data: formData, // Сеарилизуем объект
    success: function () {
        swal({
            title: "Отлично!",
            type: "success",
            timer: 2000
        });
        jQuery('#ajax_form')[0].reset();
    },
    error: function () {
        swal({
            title: "Ошибка!",
            type: "warning",
            timer: 2000
        });
    }
    });
}
```